# cannot save/retrieve value using html input in a foreach with php

Tags: php, html

For some probably obvious to anyone else reason, I cannot save the input value of my radio buttons and retrieve them with php. $_POST['answerToQuestion'] is not empty and will print the $key of each, but the value is empty. Can anyone readily see my mistake?

html:

```
<form action="answerQuestion.php" method="post">
    <?php foreach($questions as $k => $q):
        if(!$q['is_subquestion']):?>
        <div class="questionAnswer">
            <?php echo $q['body']; ?><br/>
            <div class="btn-group"  data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                <button type="button" class="btn" id="answer_yes" name="answerToQuestion[<?php echo $k; ?>]" value= 1>Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn" id="answer_no" name="answerToQuestion[<?php echo $k; ?>]" value= 0>No</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn" id="answer_na" name="answerToQuestion[<?php echo $k; ?>]" value= 2>N/A</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="hidden_2" name="answerToQuestion[<?php echo $k; ?>]" value="">

        </div>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit-form" /> 
</form>
```

php:

```
foreach($_POST['answerToQuestion'] as $key=>$value)
{
    echo ' '.$value.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: do a `var_dump($_POST)` when collecting form data, see what comes back.

Comment: shows empty string as the values: array(3) { ["answerToQuestion"]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(0) ""....

Comment: just noticed that every time that I click the radio button it refreshes the page and I have no js

Answer (score 1):

Basing this answer on the question which clearly states "my radio buttons".

You don't need to echo the `$k` variable and you should use actual radio buttons:

```
<form action="answerQuestion.php" method="post">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="answerToQuestion" value="1"> Yes</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="answerToQuestion" value="0"> No</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="answerToQuestion" value="2"> N/A</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Also, remove the spaces `value= 0` (from your example), I use quotes as well.

```
 $_POST['answerToQuestion'];
```

That should work.

Comment: Neither changing the type nor removing the index changes it.

Comment: what about removing the space where you're giving the value?

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not help either